# DC-DC Powering Sensitive IO ICs

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, high-current

I have a high-powered buck DC-DC board with low RDSON FET's (10-20 A) that powers IC's that are sensitive to noise on the IO circuitry. I've done the usual of input/output bypass caps, RC snubbers, and RC on boot pin to slow FET turn on. These IC's still don't like the noise.

When I remove the onboard DC-DC and power using and external DC-DC (~10 cm wires) everything works great, even though the external DC-DC is even noisier. Seems either increase the distance of the DC-DC components or something about longer wires is fixing the issue.

What can I try on the board itself that would "mimic" characteristics of an external DC-DC?

Answer (score 0):

1. The issue could be noise *induced* by the high-power switching supply. Put magnetic shielding around it, e.g., a [mu-metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal) box.
2. Be sure *all* lines going *into* and out from the DC-DC supply have both large (electrolytic) capacitors for low-*f* noise, and ceramic caps for high-*f* noise going to the ground plane. If using a mu-metal enclosure, use feed-through caps, as well.
3. Possibly, add series inductors to the the power supply input and output, between power supply and the caps, though likely that would *not* be needed with effective bypass caps.

Answer (score 0):

An often overlooked aspect of noise propagation is radiation. It is unfortunately easy for noise to radiate around a diff or common mode filter. This fits well in the distance-equals-solution method.

Another thing to consider is noise bandwidth. The distant power source might be noisier, but at frequencies the filters and delicate circuits can handle.